# Optimizing write performance of a 3 Node 8 Core/16G Cassandra cluster

Tags: optimization, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We have setup a 3 node performance cluster with 16G RAM and 8 Cores each. Our use case is to write 1 million rows to a single table with 101 columns which is currently taking 57-58 mins for the write operation. What should be our first steps towards optimizing the write performance on our cluster?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is look at the application that is performing the writes:

1. What language is the application written in and what driver is it using?  Some drivers can offer better inherent performance than others.  i.e. Python, Ruby, and Node.js drivers may only make use of one thread, so running multiple instances of your application (1 per core) may be something to consider.  Your question is tagged 'spark-cassandra-connector' so that possibly indicates your are using that, which uses the datastax java driver, which should perform well as a single instance.
2. Are your writes asynchronous or are you writing data one at a time?  How many writes does it execute concurrently?  Too many concurrent writes could cause pressure in Cassandra, but not very many concurrent writes could reduce throughput.  If you are using the spark connector are you using `saveToCassandra`/`saveAsCassandraTable` or something else?
3. Are you using batching?  If you are, how many rows are you inserting/updating per batch?  Too many rows could put a lot of pressure on cassandra. Additionally, are all of your inserts/updates going to the same partition within a batch?  If they aren't in the same partition, you should consider batching them up.
4. Spark Connector Specific:  You can tune the write settings, like batch size, batch level (i.e. by partition or by replica set), write throughput in mb per core, etc.  You can see all these settings [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/d8585830330ce7bd6ccd3cd09fb7812c7e166d8d/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/writer/WriteConf.scala#L63-L113).

The second thing I would look at is look at metrics on the cassandra side on each individual node.

1. What does the garbage collection metrics look like?  You can enable GC logs by uncommenting lines in conf/cassandra-env.sh ([As shown here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/conf/cassandra-env.sh#L233-L247)).   [Are Your Garbage Collection Logs Speaking to You?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt1cVudGKA8).  You may need to tune your GC settings, if you are using an 8GB heap the defaults are usually pretty good.
2. Do your cpu and disk utilization indicate that your systems are under heavy load?  Your hardware or configuration could be constraining your capability [Selecting hardware for enterprise implementations](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/planning/architecturePlanningHardware_c.html)
3. Commands like `nodetool cfhistograms` and `nodetool proxyhistograms` will help you understand how long your requests are taking (proxyhistograms) and cfhistograms (latencies in particular) could give you insight into any other possibile disparities between how long it takes to process the request vs. perform mutation operations.